# WCF: Web Service Login / Authentication: HowTo?

Tags: c#, wcf, security, authentication, wss

We have a web service (WCF in C#) that has been used on an intranet until now. Going forward we want to open it up to the internet.
Obviously we are concerned that naughty people cannot access the interfaces. What is the best practise method of ensuring this in WCF? Is it WSS?
 
I'm presuming some kind of login interface and a returned token that the client must use with every call?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have basically six options:

- Windows accounts - great in intranet, not so great in internet scenarios (built-in, configure only)
- User name/password against the ASP.NET membership system: you still need to keep a database of valid users; depending on what you want to do, this might work for you  (built-in, configure only - you need to keep track of your user base)
- Certificates on the client machines calling: only those machines that have the right certificates are allowed in; great for a closed user group, not so great in general internet facing scenarios (built-in, configure only)
- Some kind of a required header - either checked against a database (e.g. "valid header tokens"), or just checked by e.g. calculating a checksum or something - anyone who knows your "secret" header will be able to call in  (built-in, needs a little bit of coding to extract and check the header)
- Some custom solution - you can define your own authentication/authorization scenario, and customize it to your liking; requires some code on your side - but gives you ultimate flexibility (your custom code all the way)
- No checks - just leave it open to anyone (built-in, configure only)

WCF guru extraordinaire, Juval Lowy, has a great article in MSDN magazine: [Declarative WCF Security](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163382.aspx) - maybe this can give you a few additional hints and pointers. He basically defines five scenarios and discusses his recommended solution for each (and also bakes that stuff into a ready-made, attribute-based declarative framework)

Comment: You don't think that claims-based access control with WIF is an option? With federation the customer will be able to control which of his users have access to the remote system. This is often a very good selling point with regards to lay offs etc. if the system exposes critical data.

Comment: @Klaus Byskov Hoffmann: quite honestly, I don't really have much insights into claims based systems. So far, they don't seem to work too well in smaller environment - or they'd be an overkill in such a scenario. They're great for world-wide corporations with a multitude of login mechanisms - but what benefit does a single service / company have, really?

Comment: I understand where you come from. But Microsoft does seem to be aligning their product portfolio with claims based authorization. Both SqlServer and Sharepoint have upcoming versions that support it, and Active Directory already has the STS role built in. So I think that people are going to have to embrace this technology at some point. Anyway, I'm just recommending it because I work with it myself, and I get the impression that what's holding people back is the misconception that it's really hard to implement. Which it is not.

Comment: @Klaus Byskov Hoffmann: I see the many benefits of claims based identity management - just a question of whether it fits this scenario (single service/single company)

Comment: sure, you are right. The most secure/feasible solution for this particular question is probably the certificate solution you suggest.

Answer (score 2):

You should check [Windows Identity Foundation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/security/aa570351.aspx) (WIF). With WIF you can build a Security Token Service that takes care of the authentication part, so that you WCF services only have to deal with authorization. This is quite a big topic, so I suggest you look at some [whitepapers](http://claimsid.codeplex.com/) and decide if you want to use it at all, and then come back and ask some more specific questions.

Comment: I agree. This is definitely the way to go, not just for WCF services but for all web applications which need authentication services. The claims based approach decouples the authentication mechanism from applications (and is inherently reusable), and also gives a far more flexible basis for authorization. Best of all, WIF has made it quite easy to do.